# eBay API call in Node.js returns 'Input transfer has been terminated because your request timed out'

Tags: node.js, ebay-api

I want to get `SessionId` using eBay API. I am using Node.js as back-end. In the response I am getting this error:

> Input transfer has been terminated because your request timed out.

To get `sessionId` I am using following approach.

```
var xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'+
'<GetSessionIDRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">'+
 '<RuName>MyRuname</RuName>'+
'</GetSessionIDRequest>';

var options = {
host: "api.sandbox.ebay.com",
path: '/ws/api.dll',
method: "POST",
body: xml,
headers: {
    'X-EBAY-API-APP-NAME': 'my app id',
    'X-EBAY-API-DEV-NAME': 'my dev id',
    'X-EBAY-API-CERT-NAME': 'my cert id',
    'X-EBAY-API-COMPATIBILITY-LEVEL': '557',
    'X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME': 'GetSessionID',
    'X-EBAY-API-SITEID':'203',
    'Content-Type' : 'text/xml',
    'Content-Length':xml.length
}
};

var req = https.request(options, function (res) {
  console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode);
  console.log("headers: ", res.headers);

   res.on('data', function (d) {
     process.stdout.write(d);

  });

});

req.end();

req.on('error', function (e) {
   console.error('error=======', e);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error can occur if you send an empty POST body. If you look at the nodejs [docs](http://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_request_options_callback) you will see that there is no *body* option when creating the request object with *https.request*.

The correct way of setting the body in the request is to call the [*req.write*](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_request_write_chunk_encoding) method before calling *req.end*

```
var options = {
    host: "api.sandbox.ebay.com",
    path: '/ws/api.dll',
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        'X-EBAY-API-APP-NAME': 'my app id',
        'X-EBAY-API-DEV-NAME': 'my dev id',
        'X-EBAY-API-CERT-NAME': 'my cert id',
        'X-EBAY-API-COMPATIBILITY-LEVEL': '557',
        'X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME': 'GetSessionID',
        'X-EBAY-API-SITEID':'203',
        'Content-Type' : 'text/xml',
        'Content-Length':xml.length
    }
};

var req = https.request(options, function (res) {
    console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode);
    console.log("headers: ", res.headers);

    res.on('data', function (d) {
        process.stdout.write(d);
    });
});

req.on('error', function (e) {
    console.error('error=======', e);
});

req.write(xml);

req.end();
```